# queue length always zero in rabbitmq

Tags: scala, rabbitmq

```
val sslsf: SSLConnectionSocketFactory = Utility.getTrustAllSSLFactory
    val credsProvider: CredentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
      new AuthScope(rmqHost1, 15672),
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials("guest", "guest"))
val httpclient: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
    .build()

val getRequest: HttpGet = new HttpGet(rmqHost1 + "api/queues")
val response: CloseableHttpResponse = httpclient.execute(getRequest) 
for (qName <- queueNameList) {
     channel.queueDeclare(qName, true, false, false, policies)
     queueMap += (qName -> channel.queueDeclarePassive(qName).getMessageCount)
 }
```

I am trying to make an alert system on the health of my RMQ queues. For that i need the number of messages in the queue. However

```
channel.queueDeclarePassive(qName).getMessageCount)
```

is always returning 0 even if there are messages available in the queue. I only need the ready messages. Not worried about the unACKed messages as much.

I know one way would be to make an API call to api\queues and then extract the required information from there but if someone can fix the bug in this problem it will be more helpful

Thanks in advance! cheers :)

Comment: What is use non-pasive queue declaration? Does messages count then non-zero? Does actual message count (without waiting acknowledge) differs from zero?

Comment: actual message count is non zero .

Comment: Why don't you get this value directly from the HTTP API?

Comment: That is what i Have done. but i wanted to know what is wrong with this approach?